# PHPExcel: Coloring the cells?

Tags: phpexcel

I'm using the PHPExcel to generate some sheets on my server. More or less it everything works fine, but, when I try to color some rows (every second row, so the list would be easily readable) I get funny thing: the row is colored ok, but only on cells that are not filled with data. The cells that are filled with data remain white.

Here's code I use

```
            $ind = ($ind + 1) % 2;

            if($ind == 1)
            {
                $style_header = array(                  
                'fill' => array(
                    'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                    'color' => array('rgb'=>'CCC'),
                ),
                'font' => array(
                    'bold' => true,
                )
                );
                $sheet->getStyle($row)->applyFromArray( $style_header );

            }

            $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->setValue($item['qty']);
            $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->setValueExplicit($item['name']);
            $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->setValueExplicit($item['size']);
            $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row)->setValueExplicit($item['color']);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything that jumps out at me as being wrong.  Does the bold font get applied to the cells with text or is the entire style being ignored?  If the bold does get set, try flipping the order of 'fill' and 'font' within the array.  I wouldn't think that should make a difference, though.

You could also try `$sheet->getStyle('A$row:D$row')->...` as well, just to explicitly set the style for the range of cells you're using instead of the whole row.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the tip, the $sheet->getStyle('A$row:D$row') worked great. I have no idea why it wouldn't work otherwise, but it doesn't matter anymore.

Answer (score 1):

here you can get good examples
http://bayu.freelancer.web.id/2010/07/16/phpexcel-advanced-read-write-excel-made-simple/